# Saving downloaded file under original name

Tags: python

I'm trying do download some files using wget in Python, but I have a problem of saving the file under its original name and extension.

If I open the link in a browser I get the file with its original name and extension (of course). But how to do get it from the script?

To be specific, the url's are parametrized, something like:

```
path/to/file?id=123&type=logDoc
```

Comment: Could you show us some code to see what's happening?

Comment: Well, not much, I'm only calling wget.download(link) on a list of url's...

Answer (score 0):

Described perfectly in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget:

```
>>> import wget
>>> url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
>>> filename = wget.download(url)
100% [................................................] 3841532 / 3841532>
>> filename
'razorback.mp3'
```

Comment: But this is not the real file name. If you have path/to/file?id=123&type=logDoc it won't save it under the original name.